# serve arbitrary static content on the fly with cherrypy

Tags: cherrypy

I am trying to create a media server using cherrypy and cant get cherrypy to serve up files in any directory that isn't set at startup in the config. I don't want to expose the drives root directory I would prefer to expose a directory at a time as I need it. Is there away to do this?

here is the relevant snippet of my current code.

```
@cherrypy.expose
def serve_mp3(self, mp3_path):
    #cherrypy.config.update({"media":{
    #"tools.staticdir.on" : True,
    #"tools.staticdir.root" : "C:\\Documents and Settings\\sdc\\My Documents\\My Music",
    #"tools.staticdir.dir" : "",
    #"tools.staticfile.root" : "C:\\Documents and Settings\\sdc\\My Documents\\My Music"
    #}})
    static_handler = cherrypy.tools.staticdir.handler(section="/media", dir="C:\\Documents and Settings\\sdc\\My Documents\\My Music")
    cherrypy.tree.mount(static_handler, '/media')
    mp3 = mp3_path.rsplit("\\",1)[1]
    return "media/" + urllib.quote(mp3)
```

Thanks go to cyraxjoe the mess above wound up being re-factored as

```
    @cherrypy.expose
    def serve_mp3(self, mp3_path):
      mp3_path = urllib.unquote(mp3_path)
      return(cherrypy.lib.static.serve_file(mp3_path, content_type="audio/mpeg", disposition=None, name=None))
```

which worked just fine for serving an audio tag. I know as it exists this is basically front door access to my hdd but this is just a first step and the final result will be driven by a data base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should use the [functions to serve static files directly](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/refman/lib/static.html) instead of the handler, you are fighting with the tool. With the direct call of the functions you can serve any arbitrary path or file object if you like.